# How to use markdown at Rubydoc.info?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, documentation, markdown, yard

I am documenting a Ruby gem locally using YARD. When I release a new gem version, Rubydoc.info automatically starts to parse the new docs. The problem is that it's not processing my documentation markdown correctly.

### What I have in my local YARD server:

[image: Screen Shot 2017-04-26 at 23.12.57.png]

### In Rubydoc.info [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/firebase_id_token/FirebaseIdToken/Certificates):

[image: Screen Shot 2017-04-26 at 23.13.15.png]

I have set in my `.yardopts` file:

`--markup-provider=redcarpet
--markup=markdown`

And set `redcarpet` as a development dependency in my `.gemspec` file.

Any help?